# Autofit Method of Range Class Failed (Run Time Error 1004)

Tags: excel, vba

This is just part of my code. the value from the textbox here already gets copied to the specific cell in the Bank Certification worksheet. I need to make sure that cell C5 is specifically fitted regardless of the length of the text i inputted in the textbox. I tried interchanging range with cells to no avail. This problem seems so simple but I don't know why it doesn't work...

```
Dim counterparty As String  
counterparty = Sheet1.txt1.Text

Range("C5").Value = counterparty 

Sheets("Bank Certification").Select

Range("C5").Select 

Selection.AutoFit
```

Comment: Could you try refitting the entire Column instead of the particular cell.
`Columns("C:C").AutoFit`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
Dim counterparty As String
counterparty = Sheet1.txt1.Text

Range("C5").Value = counterparty

Sheets("Bank Certification").Select

Columns("C:C").Autofit
```

Comment: thanks.. this kinda works.. the error doesnt show... but right now, I'm thinking, is autofit applicable only to a specific cell? like C5!

Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Nope Autofit works only on Columns as one cell in a column cannot have a different width than the rest of the column. If that is what you require you can consider merging cells.

Comment: Also, you can get rid of the `Sheets().select` line, as it doesn't buy you anything. If you need to be more specific: `Worksheets("Bank Certification").Columns("C:C").Autofit` should do it.

Answer (score 5):

Other answers correctly state that AutoFit must be used with a column, not just a cell. However, there are some nuances to using AutoFit that I didn't understand until I started experimenting.

Either of the first two statements below will use **all** values in column C to AutoFit the width of the column. That means if there is a value in some other cell in column C (for example C10) that is wider than the value in C5, it will fit the column to the *widest cell in column C* (for example C10).

```
Range("C5").EntireColumn.AutoFit     ' Will fit to widest cell in column
Range("C:C").AutoFit                 ' Will fit to widest cell in column
```

If you want to *just* fit the column on **1 cell** (or a certain range of cells, but **not the whole column** or columns), use a statement like this:

```
Range("C5").Columns.AutoFit          ' Will fit column C to width of cell C5
```

And of course, it's always better form to write code like this when you can:

1. Fully qualify the range unless you're absolutely sure you'll only be working with one worksheet
2. Use Named Ranges or Range objects.

For example:

```
Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("MyData").Columns.AutoFit
'  or
Set AutoFitRange = Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C5")
AutoFitRange.Columns.AutoFit
```